# SSE etc. vector programming (SIMD)

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

I'm totally new to SSE programming, but have an Intel Core i7 processor.

Basically, I want to take 4 32-bit unsigned integers and cube them all (raise to the power of 3) at once. It is my understanding that the SIMD functionality of SSE and its successors make this possible, but how in the world do I go about doing it? Preferably in C but I could manage assembly if necessary.

Edit to make clear my final goal:

Then, I want to add all the cubes together to come up with a single number.

Background: I'm just trying to use SSE to optimize figuring out if a number is an Armstrong number (a three-digit number whose sum of each digit cubed is the same as the number itself). An example is 153. There seems to be no way to do this other than brute force. These are a subset of Narcissistic numbers whose sum of all digits to the power of the length of the decimal number are equal to number itself. Hopefully, I'd like to eventually expand it to be more flexible, to start I'm just doing the Armstrong numbers. As you might imagine, this came up on another site and a few of us are trying to optimize the hell out of it. By taking your ideas and my own research, I came up with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>  // SSE 4.1

__m128i vcube(const __m128i v)
{
    return _mm_mullo_epi32(v, _mm_mullo_epi32(v, v));
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        unsigned int firstDigit = i / 100;
        unsigned int secondDigit = (i - firstDigit * 100) / 10;
        unsigned int thirdDigit = (i - firstDigit * 100 - secondDigit * 10);

        __m128i v = _mm_setr_epi32(0, firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit);
        __m128 v3 = (__m128) vcube(v);

        v3 = _mm_hadd_ps(v3, v3);
        v3 = _mm_hadd_ps(v3, v3);

        if (_mm_extract_epi32((__m128i) v3, 0) == i)    
            printf ("%03d is an Armstrong number\n", i);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I had to do some type coercions to get it to compile in some systems (Solaris, at least some Linux).

So this works, but maybe it could be streamlined. Sorry I didn't post the whole task, but I was trying to break it down into steps and I wanted to make sure each digit was correctly cubed.

(END EDIT)

Thank you!

Edit: I guess I should add I'm running Mac OS X Sierra.

EDIT AGAIN:

So, let's say I make these all these unsigned shorts instead of unsigned ints and add more digits, how do I add them together when a short may not be able to hold the sum of all the digits? Is there a way to add them and store in a vector of larger variables if you know what I mean, or a plain larger number such as a UInt64?

Sorry for all the questions, but like I said I'm totally new at vector processing even though I had access to it since my first Mac G4.

Comment: Presumably all these numbers are < 2^11 ? Or do you need results > 32 bits ? Also do you need exact results, or is a little loss of precision allowed ?

Comment: Depending on the range you can use vector extensions and avoid intrinsics https://godbolt.org/g/3AicsN. But if you do 32x32 to 64 operations you need intrinsics.

Comment: The cube of a decimal digit easily fits into an ushort, so that's what you should do - `_mm_mullo_epi16` is significantly more efficient than `_mm_mullo_epi32`. You may be able to arrange it so that you can use `_mm_madd_epi16` too. `_mm_hadd_ps` is really wrong, you need `_mm_hadd_epi32` to add ints.

Comment: Changed to _mm_hadd_epi32, thanks!

Comment: SSE is really not going to help you here - most of the time in your loop is spent extracting the decimal digits and preparing the SIMD vector. You can optimise this loop a lot to reduce the amount of scalar code, but I think there are probably still better non-SIMD approaches.

Comment: Actually using the time utility, it does seem to greatly reduce the time spent executing.

Comment: So my main question now, is how to deal with the powered shorts? Is there a way with SSE to add them to a vector using larger numbers, or should I just loop through them using "regular" code and add them all together?

Comment: Or should I use the __m256i data type and instructions?

Comment: "Actually using the time utility, it does seem to greatly reduce the time spent executing" - that's probably more to do with inefficiency in your previous implementation. I have some ideas for much faster implementations, both SIMD and non-SIMD - if I get a chance later today I'll add them to an answer.

Comment: Anyway, this isn't just for optimizing this particular code, but to help me (and perhaps) others to learn SSE programming.

Answer (score 5):

If your input values are in the range 0..1625 (so that the result fits in 32 bits) then you can use [`_mm_mullo_epi32`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_mullo_epi32&expand=3726):

```
__m128i vcube(const __m128i v)
{
    return _mm_mullo_epi32(v, _mm_mullo_epi32(v, v));
}
```

---

Demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>  // SSE 4.1

__m128i vcube(const __m128i v)
{
    return _mm_mullo_epi32(v, _mm_mullo_epi32(v, v));
}

int main()
{
    __m128i v = _mm_setr_epi32(0, 1, 1000, 1625);
    __m128i v3 = vcube(v);

    printf("%vlu => %vlu\n", v, v3);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wno-format-invalid-specifier -Wno-format-extra-args -msse4 vcube.c && ./a.out
0 1 1000 1625 => 0 1 1000000000 4291015625
```

Comment: These are great, thank you very much! Now, I need to add them together. Is there a function that would do all that at once, or do I need another SSE command to do that?

Comment: Sorry - not quite sure that you mean - the function `vcube` above does what you want, no ? The rest of the code is just a demo/test harness.

Comment: I've now added a second demo, on the assumption that you want know how to apply a SIMD function to an array.

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't make it clear, I needed to add all the numbers in the vector. I figured out with: 
    `v3 = _mm_hadd_ps(v3, v3);
    v3 = _mm_hadd_ps(v3, v3);`  
I guess that's the best way... why you have to call it twice I still don't fully understand. Or is it better to just extract each one and add them together with ordinary code? All I really need is the sum of all the cubes.

Comment: Please go back and edit your question to make it clear what you want to achieve - the question says you want to cube 32 bit ints, but your latest comment suggests you want to do a horizontal add of floating point values ???

Comment: `_mm_mullo_epi32` is slower than [`_mm_madd_epi16`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PMADDWD.html) on Intel CPUs since Haswell.  When you know the input operands are small (high-half = 0), you can use `_mm_madd_epi16` as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @Laserbeak: Try vectorizing by checking 4 numbers in parallel (one in each SIMD element), instead of checking 4 digits of a single number.  Then you don't need horizontal sums, just some vertical adds and a vertical packed-compare (`_mm_cmpeq_epi32`) + movemask.  Generating the vectors of digits will probably still dominate if you do it as in the question, rather than by incrementing a vector of digits or something to avoid the scalar modulo operations.  Also note that `hadd_ps` is for packed-floats, not packed-integers.  You can't just cast `__m128i` to `__m128`.

Answer (score 3):

For `x<=2642245` you can do `x*x*x` using the `foo_SSE` function below using SSE4.1.  This takes two 32-bit unsigned intergs as input packed into the upper and lower 64-bits of a SSE register and outputs two 64-bit integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

__m128i foo_SSE(__m128i x) {
  __m128i mask = _mm_set_epi32(-1, 0, -1, 0);
  __m128i x2 =_mm_shuffle_epi32(x, 0x80);
  __m128i t0 = _mm_mul_epu32(x,x);
  __m128i t1 = _mm_mul_epu32(t0,x);
  __m128i t2 = _mm_mullo_epi32(t0,x2);
  __m128i t3 = _mm_and_si128(t2, mask);
  __m128i t4 = _mm_add_epi32(t3, t1);
  return t4;
}

int main(void) {
  uint64_t k1 = 100000;
  uint64_t k2 = 2642245;                                                                                                                                                             
  __m128i x = _mm_setr_epi32(k1, 0, k2, 0);
  uint64_t t[2];
  _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)t, foo_SSE(x));
  printf("%20" PRIu64 " ",  t[0]);
  printf("%20" PRIu64 "\n", t[1]);
  printf("%20" PRIu64 " ",  k1*k1*k1);
  printf("%20" PRIu64 "\n", k2*k2*k2);    
}
```

This can probably be improved a bit. I'm a little out of practice.

Answer (score 2):

To get a quick overview about the 3 main stages (loading, operating, storing) see the following snippet.  For integers `e0` and `e1`:

```
#include "emmintrin.h"
__m128i result __attribute__((aligned(16)));
__m128i x = _mm_setr_epi32(0, e1, 0, e0);
__m128i cube = _mm_mul_epu32(x, _mm_mul_epu32(x, x));
_mm_store_si128(&result, cube);
```

The `_mm_mul_epu32` takes the even multiples of 32bits of two _m128i registers, multiplies them and puts the result as 2-tuple of 64bits into the result register.

To get them out of there access either access them through a cast or use your compiler's convenience definition of `__m128i`, e.g. for icc:

```
printf("%llu %llu\n", result.m128i_i64[0], result.m128i_i64[1]); /* msc style */
```

Note: I'm using the [Intel Intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) for SSE primitives.

*Edited for clarity about what the code actually does.*

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but to show him how to get started with SSE the example above should do, it shows loading, operating and storing.